# Why dup2 has to be atomic? What can happen in between close(oldFd) dup(newFd)?

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, dup2, dup

There is a question in my Operating Systems test about which I'm not sure:

given the following code:

```
int fd = open("File", O_RDWR);
dup2(fd, 1);
write(1, "Hi", 2);
exit(0);
```

---

(1)How can you replace the dup2() call using others system calls?

My answer:

```
 close(1);
 dup(fd);
```

---

(2) Substituting the code of the answer (1) in the given code, what could happen during the execution of the generated executable, which underlines the necessity that dup2() is an **atomic** operation?

In this case, with the 'given' code I'm not able to find a counterexample; my counterexample is:

```
int fd = open("File", O_RDWR);
if(fork() == 0){
  write(1, "a", 1);
}
close(1);
dup(fd);
write(1, "Hi", 2);
exit(0);
```

and I say that with this example if the line 'write(1, "a", 1)' is scheduled between the 'close' and the 'dup', there will be an error because no file with fd = 1 would exist; but I'm not able to find a possible 'special case' with the code given at the beginning. I am wondering if there's ambiguity in the exercise, or I didn't understand something.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "What can happen in between close(oldFd) dup(newFd)?" - Everything.

Comment: `fork()` doesn't help, because the two processes each have their own copy of the file descriptor. On the other hand, a signal-handler or a second thread *could* easily do an `open()` or `close()` between the `close()` and the `dup()`, so the new file-descriptor used by `dup()` would *not* be the one `close()` made available.

Comment: @EOF So I can simply add a new signal handler that performs an open() and it's ok!?! thank you so much!! :)

Comment: @GiovanniCiampi: Well, if the normal (sequential) code flow literally contains `close(stdout); dup(fd);`, the race-window could be *quite* small. Which means that you'd have to be *very* precise with your signal (or second thread) to reliably hit it. On the other hand, hard to reproduce bugs are probably the worst kind.

Comment: @EOF Perfect, very good help btw!! Thank you so much!!